# Why Oozie <env-var> in Shell action doesn't work here?

Tags: shell, oozie

```
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">
        <job-tracker>${JOB_TRACKER}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${NAME_NODE}</name-node>
        <exec>echo</exec>
        <argument>$myname</argument>
        <env-var>myname=chris</env-var>
        <capture-output/>
    </shell>
```

The output is "$myname" while "chris" is expected. Can any one explain why env-var tag doesn't work here? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because when you are running an interactive session, or a shell script, then it is the **shell** executable that interprets the  `$ *  ?` symbols, and the built-in flow-control commands like `if for while`, as part of its **REPL** role. But here you requested a raw Linux executable (`echo` in this case) that takes its args as literals.

Comment: Your explain is very clear and correct, thanks!